# How to update MongoDB field using value of another field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is it possible to update a field using the value of another field?

Here is my schema

```
var timeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hours: Number,
    minutes: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Time", timeSchema);
```

I want the value of minutes to be hours * 60 when minutes become 0

Here is my code

```
Time.updateMany({}, {minutes: hours * 60});
```

My code throws an **error** which says `hours is not defined`

Is there any possible way to update minutes using the value of hours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: It does not work

Comment: @JeromeBravo : What didn't work ? What have you tried & your DB version ? what do you mean by *when minutes become 0* ?

Comment: Code: Time.updateMany({}, {$set: {minutes: $hours * 60}}); It still says that $hours is not defined. My MongoDB version is 4.2.5

Comment: @whoami I have a function that decrease the number of minutes

Comment: This is not a good solution, but its works                                                                                        db.timeCollection.find().snapshot().forEach(
    function (elemt) {
        db.timeCollection.update(
            {
                _id: elemt._id
            },
            {
                $set: {
                    minutes: elemt.hours*60
                }
            }
        );
    }
);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from MongoDB version `4.2`, You can execute aggregation pipeline in updates i.e; you can utilize certain aggregation stages/operators in [updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline). So update part will be wrapped in `[]`.

Try below query :

```
Time.updateMany({}, [{$set: {minutes: {$multiply : ['$hours', 60 ]}}}])
```

In the above query we've used `$set` alias `$addFields` stage of aggregation & [$multiply](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/multiply/index.html) aggregation operator to multiple existing `hours` field with 60 & store the value in `minutes` field.

**Note :** Just in case `.updateMany()` throws any error try the same with `.update()` with `{ multi : true }` option.